# is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?

Tags: entity-relationship

As i know optionality means the minimum cardinality of a relationship which is denoted as optional to optional, mandatory to optional, mandatory to mandatory..

And Participation denoted as bold line and a normal line.

In the Internet some refer participation as the dependency of the entity to the relationship which is also looks like identifying and non identifying relationship.

and some refer it as the minimum cardinality

What is the correct definitions of those relationships and what is the difference..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In order to understand different kinds of relationships and constraints on relationships, it's essential to understand what relationships are first. Relationships in ER are associations between keys, not between tables. A relationship can have any number of roles of different entity sets, while foreign key constraints enforce a subset constraint between two columns of one entity set.

**Total and partial participation:**

Total participation (indicated by a double or thick association line) means that all the entities in an entity set must participate in the relationship. Partial participation (indicated by a single thin line) means that there can be entities in the entity set that don't participate in the relationship.

[image: Total and partial relationship]

`Medicine` participates totally in the `Produce` relationship, meaning that `Medicine` can't exist unless `Produced` by a `Laboratory`. In contrast, a `Laboratory` can exist without `Producing` `Medicine` - `Laboratory` participates partially in the `Produce` relationsip.

**Mandatory and optional roles:**

In a relationship, roles can be optional or mandatory. This affects whether a relationship instance can exist without an entity in a given role. Mandatory roles are indicated with a solid association line, optional roles are indicated with a dotted line.

[image: Mandatory and optional entities]

Roles aren't often talked about in database tutorials, but they're an important concept. Consider a marriage - a relationship with two mandatory roles filled by the same entity set. In most relationships, the entity sets also define the roles, but when an entity set appears multiple times in a single relationship, we distinguish them in different roles.

In the example above, a `Patient` can `Purchase` `Medicine` with or without a `Prescription`.  A `Purchase` can't exist without a `Patient` and `Medicine`, but a `Prescription` is optional (overall, though it may be required in specific cases).

**Identifying relationship / weak entity:**

A weak entity is an entity that can't be identified by its own attributes and therefore has another entity's key as part of its own. An identifying relationship is the relationship between a weak entity and its parent entity.  Both the identifying relationship and the weak entity are indicated with double borders. Weak entity sets must necessarily participate totally in their identifying relationship.

[image: Identifying relationship / weak entities]

In this example, a `Prescription` contains `LineItems` which are identified by the `Prescription`'s key and a line number. In other words, the `LineItems` table will have a composite key `(Prescription_ID, Line_Number)`.

For examples of non-identifying relationships, see the previous examples. While `Medicine` participates totally in the `Produce` relationship, it has its own identity (e.g. a surrogate key, though I didn't indicate it). Note that surrogate keys always imply regular entities.

**Mandatory/optional vs total/partial participation**

Mandatory or optional roles indicate whether a certain role (with its associated entity set) is required for the relationship to exist. Total or partial participation indicate whether a certain relationship is required for an entity to exist.

Mandatory partial participation: See above: A `Laboratory` can exist without producing any medicine, but `Medicine` can't be `Produced` without a `Laboratory`.

Mandatory total participation: See above: `Medicine` can't exist without being `Produced`, and a `Laboratory` can't `Produce` something unspecified.

Optional partial participation: See above: A `Prescription` can exist without being `Purchased`, and a `Purchase` can exist without a `Prescription`.

That leaves optional total participation, which I had to think about a bit to find an example:

[image: Optional total participation]

Some `Patients` `Die` of an unknown `Cause`, but a `Cause` of death can't exist without a `Patient` `Dying` of it.

**Total/partial participation vs identifying/non-identifying relationships**

As I said before, weak entity sets always participate totally in their identifying relationship. See above: a `LineItem` must be `Contained` in a `Prescription`, it's identity and existence depends on that. Partial participation in an identifying relationship isn't possible.

Total participation doesn't imply an identifying relationship - `Medicine` can't exist without being `Produced` by a `Laboratory` but `Medicine` is identified by its own attributes.

Partial participation in a non-identifying relationship is very common. For example, `Medicine` can exist without being `Purchased`, and `Medicine` is identified by its own attributes.

**Mandatory/optional vs identifying/non-identifying relationships**

It's unusual for a relationship to have less than two mandatory roles. Identifying relationships are binary relationships, so the parent and child roles will be mandatory - the `Contain` relationship between `Prescription` and `LineItem` can't exist without both entities.

Optional roles are usually only found on ternary and higher relationships (though see the example of patients dying of causes), and aren't involved in identification. An alternative to an optional role is a relationship on a relationship:

[image: Associative entity]

By turning `Purchase` into an associative entity, we can have it participate in a `Fill` relationship with `Prescription`. To maintain the same semantics as above I specified that a `Purchase` can only `Fill` one `Prescription`.

**Physical modeling**

If we translate from conceptual to physical model (skipping logical modeling / further normalization), making separate tables for each entity and relationship, things look pretty similar, though you have to know how to read the cardinality indicators on the foreign key lines to recover the ER semantics.

[image: Physical model examples]

However, it's common to denormalize tables with the same primary keys, meaning one-to-many relationships are combined with the entity table on the many side:

[image: Denormalized died relationship]

A relationship is physically represented as two or more entity keys in a table. In this case, the entity keys - `patient_id` and `cause_of_death_id` are both found in the `Patient` table. Many people think the foreign key line represents the relationship, but this comes from confusing the entity-relationship model with the old network data model.

Comment: does this mean that all the identifying relationships are totally participating on the relationship? and can there be total and partial participations in non identifying relationships?

Comment: Yes, weak entities always participate totally in their identifying relationship, and it's possible to have either total or partial participation in a non-identifying relationship.

Comment: entity can't exist without participation in the relationship means it is a weak entity, right? i mean can there be a non-identifying relationship with a total participation.. can u give me an example.. this is too confusing..

Comment: Consider a medical aid scheme with member and dependent entity sets. Both can have their own surrogate keys so they're regular (not weak) entities. There's a 1-to-zero-or-more relationship between members and dependents (not an identifying relationship since both entity types have their own identity). While members can exist independently, they will not register dependents without a main member, so dependents must participate totally in the relationship.

Comment: but then isnt it what we called as optionality.. which is again the total and partial participation..?

Comment: In the example above, the member role in the relationship is mandatory - every relationship instance must involve a member.  However, members can exist without dependents and hence don't participate totally in the relationship.

Comment: The dependent role is mandatory too while dependents participate totally - thus the two concepts aren't the same.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178564/what-is-the-difference-of-partiality-and-optionality-when-drawing-er-diagrams for an example

Comment: Im sorry for troubling.. but i dont get the point.. can u describe the above with all six possibilities.. (total, partial, mandatory, optional, identifying, non-identifying)

Comment: if an entity is participating totally in a relationship, does it means its always mandatory?

Comment: and in the example in stackoverflow.com/questions/38178564/ how to show a mandatory partial participation? i mean if optionality shown by a dashed line, total participation showed by double lines and partial participation shown by a normal line.. how to show these together?

Comment: I rewrote and expanded my answer with examples. Hope this helps.

Comment: I cant thank u enough for this help.. I finally understood the concepts clearly.. :) thank u so much for the effort u have put on to it.

Comment: "Medicine participates totally in the Produce relationship, meaning that Medicine can't exist unless Produced by a Laboratory." This is not so. (Or at least is unclear, if you mean a *tuple* can't exist.) Total participation does not imply existence. Here you mean "Medicine can't exist unless Produced by a Laboratory" *thus* "Medicine participates totally in the Produce relationship". You could give an additional example independent of existence, eg total participation of medicine types packaged in bottle types.