# What is the difference of partiality and optionality when drawing ER diagrams

Tags: entity, entity-relationship, erd

Partial relationships are shown by single lines total relationships are shown by double lines. And in some ER diagrams optional and mandatory relationship is shown by a dotted line and a single line respectively.

What is the exact difference of definitions between these concepts? Please use an example if possible.

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same

Comment: Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/322721/erd-for-a-lab-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

[image: ERD example]

A `Patient` or a `Laboratory` may exist independently of any relationship. Some `Patients` may `Purchase` `Medicine`, and some `Laboratories` may `Produce` `Medicine`, hence those entity sets participate partially in their relationships.

`Medicine` cannot exist without being `Produced` by a `Laboratory`, thus `Medicine` participate totally in the `Produced` relationship. `Medicine` can exist without being `Purchased` hence `Medicine` participate partially in the `Purchase` relationship.

A `Patient` may `Purchase` some `Medicine` without a `Prescription`, thus a `Prescription` is optional to the `Buys` relationship. In contrast, a `Purchase` cannot exist without a `Patient` and `Medicine`, hence those roles are mandatory to the relationship.  In the `Produced` relationship, both roles are mandatory.

The basic difference here is that cardinality constrains the existence of relationships, while participation constrains the existence of entities. When a role in a relationship set is mandatory, it means a relationship instance can't exist without an entity filling that role. When an entity set participates totally in a relationship, it means an entity can't exist without being related.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really cleared out things for me :)