# ER Diagram and constraints

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I can't model the following rule: "For each screening a seat can have only one ticket".

[image: Here's the diagram. I edited the diagram to fix the cardinalities.]

Comment: Do you want to know about modeling techniques or how to implement a 1..1-0..1 relation? Please, state your question properly.

Comment: Instead of 3 binary relationships, a single ternary relationship might be more useful.

Comment: @BorisShchegolev I am not a native speaker. Anyway, I would like to know how to implement a relation between those 3 entities such that there cannot be two tickets related to both the same seat and screening.

Comment: @reaanb Hi, I edited the diagram because I got the cardinalities wrong. Anyway, I tried using a single ternary relationship but then each seat is related to many screening-ticket couples, so how can I make sure there are not two tickets related to both the same screening and the same seat? (sorry for my english)

Comment: can you share the whole exercise?

Answer (score 0):

The stated business rule says "only one", clearly hinting at uniqueness of something.

How are you supposed to model "uniqueness of something" using this particular ER dialect ?  It doesn't look like it's very well suited for this puprpose.

Comment: Hi @ErwinSmout, I am not a native speaker so maybe I did not phrase my question correctly. I have to model a movie theater booking system and I am stuck at the ER diagram because I don't know how to make sure there aren't two seats related to both the same seat and the same screening. Initially thought I could do that using the cardinalities, but I am not sure about that anymore. Anyway, I must use that ER dialect because that's what my university professor wants.

Comment: can you share the whole exercise?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I wanted to model it as:

[image: Seating ternary relationship]

(For more about the notation, see my answer to [is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same/38035173#38035173))

But this only enforces the functional dependency:

```
(Screening, Seat) -> Ticket
```

and not

```
Ticket -> Screening, Seat
```

So this may be a better option:

[image: Seating ER diagram]

The diamond-in-rectangle is an associative entity - a relationship that is the subject of another relationship.