# ER diagram: Total participation and weak entities

Tags: database, entity-relationship, rdbms, erd, weak-entity

Even though I understand what a weak entity is and the definition of total participation I find it hard to distinguish what to use in practice.

[image]

In this example I can't understand why the restaurant is not a weak entity. A restaurant can't exist without dishes. The same goes for dish-ingredients--a dish with 0 ingredients cannot exist.

So, why are restaurant-dish and dish-ingredient only represented with a total participation and not as weak entities too?

Comment: Total participation isn't the same as an identifying relationship. Weak entities are determined by how they're identified, not by an existence dependency. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same/38035173#38035173

Answer (score 2):

**Restaurant** is not a weak entity because it **can** exist on its own. The same rule applies to **Ingredients**. Ingredients don't need do be put within any dish, but a dish can't exist without any ingredients. Dish cannot exist if there is no corresponding restaurant serving that particular dish. Consider a menu with dishes that doesn't belong to any restaurant. What would be the purpose of it in your model?

Are you sure you understand the purpose of weak entity and not think of it the other way around as it currently stands?

Comment: So the dish- ingredients relationship is a identifying relationship too right? (with the dish weak entity and "Contains" identifying"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships