# Weak entities and foreign keys

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Quoting Wikipedia, a weak entity "must use a foreign key in conjunction with its attributes to create a primary key." , and "is existence-dependent on another entity". 
But can't an entity be existence-dependent on another entity without having (part of) the PK the FK ?

In the classical Order - OrderLine - Product relation, OrderLine is a weak entity because its PK consists of the two FK's from the others entities, say orderID and productID.

But what about the Order entity ? Let's say it looks like this:

```
Order( orderID   - not null, Primary key,
    costumerID - not null, Foreign key,
    date,
    status,
    ...)
```

It's clear enough that an order can't exist without a costumer(costumerID), but at the same time, costumerID is not part of the Primary key.

1. So, in this case, is the Order entity a weak one, or not ?
2. What if we had omitted the NOT NULL constraint of the FK customerID ? Order wouldn't be a weak entity anymore, right ?

Answer (score 2):

An entity can be existence-dependent on (a relationship with) another entity without being a weak entity. This is called total participation, and indicated in ER diagrams with a double role line.

In your example, `OrderLine` would be a weak entity if its PK consisted of `orderID` and a distinguishing attribute, e.g. `line_number`. If its PK consisted of two FKs, we would call it a relationship instead.

Your `Order` example shows total participation in its relationship with `Customer` (the relationship is represented by the two entity key columns `(orderID,customerID)`). It's not a weak entity since it has its own identifier, i.e. `orderID`. If we omitted the NOT NULL constraint, `Order` would be in partial participation in its relationship with `Customer`.

Also see my answer to [is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same)