# When does one use ternary relationships instead of binary ones in a database?

Tags: database, relationship, erd, ternary

I have a problem, it is as follows:

An internet store wants to send e-mails to customers. It wants to keep a database to record what messages have been sent to which customer. Suppose an e-mail has a message id (M-id), a subject (Subject), and message body (Body). The customer is identified by his e-mail address, other customer information includes name (Name), gender (Gender), and address (Address).

**When the internet store sends an email to the customer, SendDate is recorded.**

Now we're suppposed to draw an ERD with the information given above and then draw a relational database schema.

Based on the bold statement, I drew the following ERD, not knowing what to do with cardinality and participation:
[image] 
The answer to the problem is this:
[image]
Note that Send is a weak entity, and that there is full participation between email and contains, sends and customer.

Q1: Why can't I use a ternary relationship for this example?

Q2: Regardless of this problem, in a ternary relationship, how do we determine the cardinality and participation?

Q3: How does one arrive to the final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Why can't I use a ternary relationship for this example?

The question indicates that e-mail is recorded on behalf of a single internet store. There's no need to specify it in each association, the entire database belongs to the store.

If you were modeling e-mail sent to customers at multiple internet stores, a ternary relationship would be appropriate.

> Q2: Regardless of this problem, in a ternary relationship, how do we determine the cardinality and participation?

The cardinality of each role in a relationship is the number of values in that role that can be associated with each valid combination of the other roles. E.g. if you have a relationship `(A, B, C)`, then the cardinality of `A` is the number of values from `A` that can appear for each valid combination of `(B, C)`. If `(B, C)` is a superkey then the cardinality of `A` is one.

Participation is simpler: for each role, must all the values in the associated entity set necessarily participate in the relationship, or can some exist independently? I suggest you also see my answer to this question: [is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same/38035173#38035173).

> Q3: How does one arrive to the final answer?

I disagree with the final answer you posted. In the ER model, weak entity sets can't have multiple identifying relationships, and usually have a weak key. I suspect the author may be using some network data model concepts (such as conflating relationships with foreign key constraints and/or thinking only entities can have attributes).

My own answer to the question would look like this:

[image: E-mails sent to customers ER diagram]