# Differences between has and contains relationship in ERD?

Tags: erd

**ERD from Wikipedia:**

[image: ERD from Wikipedia]

I'm confused to distinguish "has" and "contains" relationship in ERD, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the linked diagram from Wikipedia, both `Has` and `Contains` are one-to-many relationships (1..n) with total participation of `Character` in the relationship (double association line). Total participation means every `Character` **must** be related to an `Account` and a `Region`.

However, the `Has` relationship is marked as an identifying relationship (double-bordered diamond) and `Character` is marked as a weak entity set (double-bordered rectangle). This means that the identifying attributes of `Character` include the identifying attributes of `Account`. `Character` has a weak key `CharName`, which must be combined with `AcctName` to fully identify a `Character`. In other words, the primary key of the `Character` table will be composite: `AcctName, CharName`.

Note that these comments apply to the example ERD, not to ERD in general. `Has` and `Contains` aren't types of relationships - in general, a relationship can be called anything and have any combination of the features available in ER theory.

Also, see my answer to [Is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same/38035173#38035173)

Comment: thanks for your explanation, it's very helpful to understand the attached ERD.