# Er diagram one-to-many relationship - Participation constraints

Tags: database-design, erd, entity-relationship

When drawing ER diagram with Chen notation. **Do all 1:N relationship be drawn with Total participation constraints** double lines?
For example: one Invoice can have multiple payments. And a payment must have a invoice number as a payment is done for an invoice. This has 1:n relationship so how do i put this in a diagram?
[erd example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2FAE.png)

Answer (score 0):

No, all 1:N relationships don't require full participation of the entity set on the many side. A person can be in one building, while a building can hold multiple persons, but a building can be empty, and people can be outside.

In your example, must every `Payment` necessarily be related to an `Invoice`? If so, then indicate total participation of `Payment` in the `Received` relationship by using a double association line.

A double-bordered diamond indicates an identifying relationship. Using that would indicate that a `Payment` isn't identified by its own attributes, but by its `Invoice` and a weak key. A weak key is usually an ordinal or role that isn't unique by itself, but serves to subdivide the parent entity. For example, consider a model where `Invoices` have numbers, and `Payments` are identified by an `Invoice` number together with a sequence number to indicate the 1st, 2nd or 3rd payment on that `Invoice`.

Weak entity sets necessarily participate totally in their identifying relationships, but keep in mind that total participation doesn't imply an identifying relationship.

See also my answer to [Is optionality (mandatory, optional) and participation (total, partial) are same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034049/is-optionality-mandatory-optional-and-participation-total-partial-are-same/38035173#38035173)

Comment: So, regardless of 1:N or N:M we have to only think of, if entity is necessarily be related to other.

Comment: Yes, and the same applies in ternary and higher relationships, e.g. M:N:P